# Objective-C: How to check a number is between two values

Tags: objective-c

Going a little nuts here with a super noob issue. How do a check if and int is between two values i.e. want to see if x<100 && x>50 I have tried:

```
if(x<100 && x>50){
 ..
}
```

but not having any joy??

Comment: is x an integer or an NSNumber?

Comment: In what way does that not work?  Apart from the fact that I would put the x > 50 test first, that is exactly what I would do.

Comment: When asking for help with something that doesn't seem to work, it's helpful to explain what is or isn't happening. Here, it'd help to show the declaration of `x`, the nearest place where you assign a value to `x`, and some characterization of the failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your compiler is broken there is nothing wrong with that code. There is probably something wrong with `x`

As Sascha stated in the comments make sure that `x` is not an `NSNumber`. The reason for this is if `x` is an `NSNumber` then the value stored in it is a pointer which value would likely be much higher than 100 (0x4FBC60 for example) and you would want to compare against the `-(int)intValue`.

Other things to consider are comparing against the right data. While implicit number conversions work well you may want to use the same literal comparison as your data type.

```
unsigned long long x = 51ull;
if(x > 50ull && x < 100ull)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

OP, your code seems fine to me. However, if anyone else arrived here wondering if there is an easy function to see if a number is between two other numbers, then I am going to propose a solution.

It is possible to use a #define:

```
#define BETWEEN(value, min, max) (value < max && value > min)
```

Usage will be like so:

```
if (BETWEEN(5, 0, 10))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 66;
if(x>50 && x<100){
  // do what you need here
}
```

Or

```
NSNumber *x = @66;
if([x intValue]>50 && [x intValue]<100){
  // do what you need here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, I think it cuts out early if the first condition, second, etc (with multiple conditions) is false... so

```
if( 50<x && x<100 )
```

.. would first check `50<x` ... if that's false, then it'll skip the `x<100` check.

However, there's some C-like derivative languages that don't have this advanced checking. Instead, they pull all bools first then do a compare.

EG: I've been doing some coding in HLSL (high-level shader language) for Direct X. It doesn't short out if an early condition is false; it likes to check every one and then decide after. So...

```
if (50<x && x<100)
```

... both parts get evaluated, then if either is false it moves on. Since all parts get evaluated anyways, I just end up going with...

```
if( 50 < x < 100)
```

If you wanted to be anal retentive in these situations you can code-bloat by branching a bit...

```
if (50 < x)
{
  if (x < 100)
  {do A}
  else
  {do B}
}
else
{do B}
```

It's more code, but it forces the HLSL compiler to cut out of decisions one at a time instead of wasting time evaluating all the bools when one is already false.