# Return value closest to 0 including negative numbers

Tags: objective-c, return, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` which I would like to return the corresponding key nearest zero (including those with negative numbers):

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"David" : @-89,
                       @"Bobby" : @61,
                       @"Nancy" : @-8,
                       @"Sarah" : @360,
                       @"Steve" : @203
                      };
```

So in this case `Nancy` would be closest... 
How can I do that? I searched but came up empty.

Comment: Update your question with what you tried so far. Explain what issue you have with the code.

Comment: I've tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195053/searching-a-nsarray-for-the-nearest-number), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754308/finding-the-closest-int-value-from-a-set-of-int-values-in-objective-c), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086770/pick-closest-nsnumber-from-array), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651229/objective-c-how-to-check-a-number-is-between-two-values). The issue is that none of them deal with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate the values and keep track of which one is closest to zero. Use `abs` to work with absolute values.

Disclaimer - below code is not tested - could be typos. It also assumes integers. Adjust as needed to support floating point values.

```
NSDictionary *dict = ... // your dictionary
NSInteger closestValue = NSIntegerMax;
NSString *closestKey = nil;
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
    NSNumber *value = dict[key];
    NSInteger number = (NSInteger)labs((long)[value integerValue]);
    if (number < closestValue) {
        closestValue = number;
        closestKey = key;
    }
}

NSLog(@"Closest key = %@", closestKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple max min problem,

```
NSString *curMinKey = [dict.allKeys firstObject];
NSInteger curMinVal = ABS([[dict objectForKey:curMinKey] integerValue]);
for(id key in dict) {
    if(curMinVal > ABS([[dict objectForKey:key] integerValue])) {
        curMinKey = key;
        curMinVal = ABS([[dict objectForKey:key] integerValue]);
    }
}
/// curMinKey is what you are looking for
```

Comment: This code won't work as-is. You can't pass an `NSNumber` to the `abs` function.

Comment: @maddy: Can you explain `won't work`? I tried it and it seemed to return the correct result.

Comment: It seems there is a warning `Using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of complex type, Use function 'cabsf' instead`. When I include the `<complex.h>` header and change it to `cabsf` the warning then becomes an error: `Passing 'id _Nullable' to parameter of incompatible type '_Complex float'`

Comment: @Yoshi Miro try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321205/absolute-value-of-nsinteger

Comment: @rmaddy code worked but with warnings, since that code was posted from mobile device, could not find correct function/method.

Comment: @YoshiMiro do not use `cabsf`, I have updated my answer to use `ABS` macros.

Comment: This code is still incorrect. You can't simply cast `NSNumber` objects to `NSInteger`. You need to use `[[dict objectForKey:key] integerValue]`.